# CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY not effective

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am using CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY to pin the certificate. I also set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to 1 and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST as mentioned in the docs.

I took the certificate file of the destination server and created sha256 base64 string as mentioned in curl docs for CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY. Setting the valid sha string as "sha256//sddgdSDFSQWbGGRFr9rugEih7jghJwjj0xqcvbo=", or changing few characters in this string, and setting it as PINNEDPUBLICKEY results in the curl call to be successful. I was expecting invalid sha to result in error CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH. But it did not.

I saved the certificate from chrome browser to der file and pem file, and gave the path to the curl opt PINNEDPUBLICKEY. Still valid key and invalid key, both result in success.

Shouldnt an invalid string result in error? I am not sure if PINNEDPUBLICKEY  is working or not. May be I am missing something? Any inputs would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: could be a libcurl bug, could be something else...

Comment: fwiw : I am using libcurl 7.42 version. Wonder if it is a version upgrade issue.

Comment: You might want to take this to the curl-library list instead. The functionality (using wrong pinned key) is btw verified in curl's test 2035.

Comment: Also, I needed to upgrade my curl library from 7.42 to 7.48. That fixed the issue and provided the proper error code that I was expecting for a wrong public key.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my issue: I needed to upgrade my curl library from 7.42 to 7.48. That fixed the issue and provided the proper error code that I was expecting for a wrong public key.